# Merge multiple text files as one CSV file

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, merge

I have couple of files which contain data like this:

```
file1.txt
abc
def
hij

file2.txt
def
abc
qlm

file3.txt
def
lop
tmn
```

desired output:

mergedfile.csv

```
file1      file2     file2
abc        def       def
def        abc       lop
hij        qlm       tmn
```

Comment: Do you have attempted writing anything yet? If not, I'm confident that the below link will give you what you need to get started along with some searching around. https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python Documentation [CSV File Reading and Writing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)
For instance, **lowest memory** footprint:

```
import io, csv
fieldnames = [file1, file2, file3]
with io.open(csv_file, 'w', newline='') as fh_csv, \
    open(file1) as fh1, \
    open(file2) as fh2, \
    open(file3) as fh3:

    writer = csv.writer(fh_csv, delimiter='\t')
    writer.writerow(fieldnames)

    while True:
        out = []
        for fh in [fh1, fh2, fh3]:
            out.append( fh.readline().strip('\n') )

        if all(out):
            writer.writerow(out)
        else:
            break
```

**Output**:

```
file1.txt   file2.txt   file3.txt  
abc         def         def  
def         abc         lop  
hij         qlm         tmn
```

***Tested with Python:3.4.2***

Answer (score 0):

my way:

```
import pandas as pd
df1=pd.read_csv('file1.txt',names=['file1'])
df2=pd.read_csv('file2.txt',names=['file2'])
df3=pd.read_csv('file3.txt',names=['file3'])
result=pd.concat([df1,df2,df3],axis=1)
result.to_csv('mergedfile.txt',index=False)
```

or more python style:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

def merge_files(file_list, export_file):
    df_list = [pd.read_csv(
        one_file, names = [os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(one_file))[0]]
    ) for one_file in file_list if os.path.isfile(one_file)]
    all_df=pd.concat(df_list,axis=1)
    all_df.to_csv(export_file, index=False)


if __name__=='__main__':
    sample_files=['./file1.txt', '../temp/file2.txt','file3.txt']
    merge_files(sample_files,"mergedfile.txt")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to write some code yourself：

My way:

```
file_list=['a','b','c']

open("o","w").write("\n".join([" ".join(i).replace("\n","") for i in list(zip(*[list(open(i)) for i in file_list]))]))
```

Result:

```
file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt
abc def def
def abc lop
hij qlm tmn
```

---

I read the three files and append the data into three lists and then use [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to aggregates elements.If you want to be compatible with `Python2.x` and `Python3.x` you can add this to the top of your code:

```
try:
    from itertools import izip as zip
except ImportError:
    pass
```

Then I remove the `\n` character,and combine the list and write them into a file.